# PHP: How to set the value of a variable through another variable?

Tags: php

I have a variable that calls an item, but what I have to display is the description of his category. So the structure I figured out is something like this willing that writing `$item1` in `$var1` it displays `"Bla Bla Bla"` (the value of `$cat1`):

```
$var1 = $item1;
$item1 = $cat1;
$cat1 = 'Bla Bla Bla';
```

Believe or not it doesn't work :-)
I am a novice with php, sorry to ask stupid questions! And thank you so much to help!

Comment: Hi, not sure exectly what you are trying to achieve

Comment: are you maybe trying something like $var1->cat1 ? just guessing here

Comment: Yes and my english does not help (I am Italian)... indeed I would like to write <?php echo $var1; ?> in my page and display "Bla Bla Bla" but I need to use those 3 variables

Comment: why do you need 3 variables ?

Comment: Because it is the product, the category and the family... so when I set the product I need also to display the Family Description

Comment: if what i think you mean is correct echoing json_encode($var1) and pasting the result here will help

Comment: It looks like you need to explore arrays instead.

Comment: If you reverse the order it works! Why have you used uncreated variables before creating and setting them

Comment: arrays should be the best because I have houndreds of relations to create... can you paste me an example please?

Comment: reversing it works!!!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assignation of values in most common programm languajes is up to down (cascade programming style)

```
$var1 = $item1;  <--- at this point $item1 is "empty" or null
$item1 = $cat1;  <--- at this point $cat1 is empty too
$cat1 = 'Bla Bla Bla';  <--- here $cat1 take value 'Bla Bla Bla'
```

so, you have to invert order of assignation like this:

```
$cat1 = 'Bla Bla Bla';
$item1 = $cat1;
$var1 = $item1;
```

the output show 'Bla Bla Bla' for $cat1 $item1 and $var1
hope this help.